# Update two or more column to the same value SQL in a DRY manner

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to do something like this to set foo and bar to the same value and I don't like to **repeat the value**, and not working.

```
update t1 set foo = bar = 10;
```

For now, I must do that in this way, this is working, but need a DRY way to do this:

```
update t1 set foo = 10, bar = 10;
```

Also tried but `bar` getting pervious value of `foo`:

```
update t1 set foo = 10, bar = foo;
```

Is this achievable in SQL (Also Postgres would be nice)?

Comment: Your second way is fine.

Comment: I know (edited my question), but I like a DRY way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is anything in standard SQL that could do this.

But in Postgres, you can use an update from a VALUES clause:

```
update foo
  set bar = t.value, 
      foo = t.value
from (
  values (10) 
) as t(value);
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=d91dfb6112a9d86600001f268d49f5ce)

Answer (score 1):

This logic:

```
update t1
    set foo = bar = 10;
```

Does not do what you expect.  It is parsed as:

```
update t1
    set foo = (bar = 10);
```

The second part `(bar = 10)` is interpreted as a boolean expression, which returns `true`, `false`, or `null`.

Your second method is the correct way to do what you want.

You can *also* express this as:

```
update t1
    set (foo, bar) = (10, 10)
```

However, I don't see any particular advantage to using this form.

Or, if you wanted to specify the value only once, you could use `from`:

```
update t1
    set foo = v.val, bar = v.val
    from (values (10)) v(val);
```

Comment: Thanks, you are right, I had edited my question, I need a DRY way to do that.

Comment: As you said your suggested way is not my answer.